# Running a code remotely with screen but killed shortly after logout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, gnu-screen

I often run a code on a remote Linux/Ubuntu desktop with the use of `screen`. So I log in through SSH, start a screen, start the job, detach the screen and everything works fine. However, recently the job is being killed shortly after I logoff the SSH connection. I also tried using `nohup` but this shows the same problem. I am quite sure that the code is not the problem since it has been well tested and runs ok on my laptop. Also there is no error output and the standard output shows that the code stopped in the middle of the run for no reason. Any ideas on what might go wrong here or how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to enable and check the log... [Give a look here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Logging). If you have a script you can insert some lines to check how it proceeds. Add as last line an `echo "[$$] [$(date)] Here we end " >> $HOME/MyLog_$$.log`, or some other lines just after a command execution as `echo Last command run was ["!:0"] with arguments ["!:*"]  and [$?] is the exit code of this command  >>$HOME/MyLog_$$.log`

Comment: Please try issuing as `sudo`, in the directory `/var/log`, the following command: `grep -nrI screen | grep -v apt-get | grep -v dist-upgrade` and see whether anything useful shows up.